# Annoying chrome debugger blue arrow

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I open Developer Tools in chrome, I always see the blue arrow activated by itself and on the Web page ,  I see 
an message of `"Paused in debugger"` and blue arrow icon next to it to click and move forward.Everytime I have to click on it and then move forward which is annoying.  I haven't set any breakpoints and don't want to stop and move forward. Is there a way I can disable this activated blue arrow icon? Here is the image below:

[image]